# Using the Windows 7's fax service

Tags: windows-7, services, modem, fax

I use Windows 7 ultimate on my computer. And know that it's possible to use this OS as fax device to send and recieve faxes. I have an ADSL modem which the telephone line is attached to it and a splitter (just as other ADSL modem used in homes) is attached to the line socket on the wall. The ADSL modem is attached to the back of my case by an ethernet cable (which has provided the Internet for me) but whatever I look at the back of my case I don't see a port for pluging a telephone line socket into it! I think I don't have that classic modem (which was used for dial-up) installed on my motherboard. 
Now, is there any way to use the fax service of Windows 7 this way?

Comment: What you describe requires first a fax line and second a 56k modem.

Comment: I know of a 56kbps modem (it is an old modem which was attached to the motherboard for dial-up, yes?) but what do you mean by fax line? Is that that ordinary copper wire telephone line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first attach classing modem into mother board > install the drivers first.
Now use a telephone line splitter that will bring 2 telephone line cables. Put one into ADSL modem and put the second one into the "Line" port into classic modem.
Now go to fax and service and configure the necessary settings.

Comment: OW, so when the line is busy (I use the fax service of Windows) can I also use the ADSL Internet? Don't make those two the frequency clash (between frequency used for ADSL and the fax service) when utilizing both at the same time?

Comment: No my bro, It doesn't affect any of both, I currently using both services at the same time without any tension

Comment: OK. Thank you very much my sister (if the name of the "Rebbeca" is a female name)!

Comment: remain this issue at the right place.

Comment: At the right place!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the built in Fax and scan along with a dial up modem.  However your line may not be compatible.  It 'may' work but there is a very good chance it will not.

For reliability you will want a stand alone line just for phone and/or fax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your answer isn't in a right direction of my question but as a thanks to your answer I give +1 to you.

Comment: yeah sorry it wouldn't let me use the add comment, but i think it was cause i was being dumb ;-)  Thanks!

Comment: No you wasn't being dumb. Such mistakes can happen for anyone, mate. You are welcome:)